# How to set R to use all of the width of my terminal?

Tags: linux, r

I am running interactive `R` in terminal, however it doesn't use all of the width of the terminal. It only use 72 characters out of 226. It is very uncomfortable to read any data with a lot of columns displayed in interactive `R`.

I am using `urxvt` on `debian 9,8`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See `?option`:

> ```
>  ‘width’: controls the maximum number of columns on a line used in
>       printing vectors, matrices and arrays, and when filling by
>       ‘cat’.
>
>       Columns are normally the same as characters except in East
>       Asian languages.
>
>       You may want to change this if you re-size the window that R
>       is running in.  Valid values are 10...10000 with default
>       normally 80.  (The limits on valid values are in file
>       ‘Print.h’ and can be changed by re-compiling R.)  Some R
>       consoles automatically change the value when they are
>       resized.
> ```

To query the value:

```
R> getOption("width")
[1] 80
```

To change the value (add this to `~/.Rprofile` to change it permanently):

```
options("width"=200)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just found the following. Seems to work properly but I've little to no testing.

```
options(width=Sys.getenv("COLUMNS"))
options(setWidthOnResize=TRUE)
```

The former can be wrap into a function to run at startup and the latter can be added to your `.Rprofile` too.